# Why is my object black in rendered shading mode?

Tags: modeling, light, lighting

I am quite new to using Blender, currently using the 2.8 Beta Version, and I decided to make a Low-Poly Island from a [tutorial I found on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lj643VmTsg&t=641s&frags=pl%2Cwn)

In the tutorial, he added a Light and changed it to the "Sun" setting, which I did. He changed the color of the light, made sure the Strength was all the way up (at 10), and turned *Contact Shadows* on. When he put it into rendering mode, it displayed a beautiful source of light that he was able to move around into the perfect angle, when I put it into rendering mode, and my model was all black, no light to be found.

I've tried everything I could, looking up tutorials on how to fix it, playing around with the settings, and after about 2 hours of attempting to get the lighting to work, I never got it. I've rewatched the video numerous times to make sure I followed everything step by step, and I could not find any possible errors or mistakes. I am doing this render as a project for my Digital Arts II class in High School.

[image: This is what my model looked like.]

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51602

Comment: make sure you added a material to the mesh, and if possible, share the .blend file

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Suggest you put your file here: http://pasteall.org/blend/ and add a link to it in your query.

Comment: You should use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to post your .blend file

Comment: For some reason it worked after I pressed <kbd>/</kbd> so maybe try that sorry if it doesn't work though

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you are not actually in render mode. I just downloaded the exact file you linked, opened it, pressed z and went into render view, and the material was not entirely black, it showed up as below:

[image]

What process are you using to go into render mode? It works fine for me with your same file, so I would guess that you are in some other mode of displaying it.

Comment: I manually press the Render Mode icon next to the "Shading" drop-down menu, and once I do that, everything is all black for me. Can you download the download that you have (the one that works fine for you) so you can send it to me so I can see if it works on my end? I'm curious to see if it's a problem on my end, and once I figure that out, I can hopefully narrow things down.

Comment: There's nothing for me to send to you, since the file I have is the same one as the file you posted on pasteall.org - I didn't change anything. One question. If you use the 'Render' dropdown menu and choose 'Render Image', is it still black?

Comment: Yup, it's still completely black. http://xomf.com/hjjbw

Comment: Well, I guess I'm going to say that it has to be a problem with your computer, since the exact blender file you uploaded works fine for me. Are you sure you didn't change the file since uploading?

Sorry I can't help, but I really have no idea at this point.

Comment: Positive. Something to also keep in mind though, I'm using a Macbook, but I don't think that's the issue, but I could very well be mistaken.

Comment: I have a macbook pro, and it works perfectly for me, so I have no idea. What version of blender are you using? (I have 2.80)

Comment: I have the 2.8 Beta Version.

Comment: The thing is though, I don't know what WOULD be wrong with my computer that's causing this error, because judging by what you said, it loaded fine for you, but whenever I load it up, it just appears all black.

Comment: If you uploaded a video of your process from opening the file to rendering it, I might be able to see something, but I probably can't really help you here.

Comment: https://youtu.be/R-TibwHfWrc

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I went to viewport shading and turned off "Scene World".