# Bug? Material Preview mode shows only black objects (Eevee and Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine

Per se, I'm not new to Blender, but after 2.8, and after not using it in a while, it sort of feels like I am again. I'm starting to dip my toes back into it by following the "Blender Fundamentals 2.8" playlist on YouTube.

Along the way, I noticed a little hiccup.

Firstly,

- OS: Windows 10 Pro
- CPU: Intel Core i7 920
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTS 250
- (Other info available on request)

**Reproducing the issue:**

1. Click "File / New / General".
2. Change the active workspace mode to "Shading".
3. Make sure Viewport Shading is set to Material Preview and the Render Engine is set to either Eevee or Cycles.
4. See the black cube.

I must be an idiot or something. I've looked all over for some solution or explanation, but absolutely nothing has proved fruitful. Anything that seemed promising applied to Blender 2.79 or earlier.

**Notes:**

- I had no Add-ons installed.
- Unless I utterly forgot something, I haven't modified the Startup File.
- The Render Preview mode doesn't have any problems.
- I just updated my GPU drivers today. It *is* a fairly old GPU, so maybe  that could have something to do with it. I dunno.

Actually, here's a screenie of what I see after all the aforementioned steps have been taken. Perhaps someone keener than I can spot something amiss.

[image]

Thanks for any help and/or directions!

Comment: Greetings. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137734/why-is-my-object-black-in-rendered-shading-mode  There is also a question re material HDRI previews being black as well.  Which version are you using?  Can type `bpy.app.version` into the python console (I'm currently using 2.83.3)  or look at top of splash screen.   If your version is 2.80 would upgrade.

Comment: The graphic card seems to be compatible: https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: Hi batFINGER, thanks for your reply. I typed that in and it says 2.82.7.

Comment: Hi lemon, thanks for the information. I'm not sure what's wrong, but I guess I'm glad I'm not crazy, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I recently switched over to a new computer with a much-improved card: I'm guessing there was something wrong with my old card.